# Centering text in a valign without finetuned column width

Tags: align, tex-core, plain-tex

Currently, I have the following valign output from this code (Plain TeX):

```
\def\make#1{{\hsize1.5in\vfil\centerline{\strut #1}\vfil\hrule}}
\valign{\hrule\make{#}&&\make{#}\cr\noalign{\vrule}
    Dimensions (in)&\multispan{9}\make{33$\times$32}&\multispan{7}\make{24$\times$24}&\multispan{7}\make{17$\times$16}&\multispan{3}\make{17$\times$16}&\multispan{3}\make{8$\times$7}&\multispan{4}\make{8$\times$7}\cr\noalign{\vrule}
    Pit Depth (cm)&1.3&1.4&1.1&1.8&2.2&1.4&1.2&2.4&1.8&2.0&2.5&0.5&1.2&1.2&1.0&1.5&1.3&1.2&0.9&2.2&1.2&2.0&1.8&1.3&1.5&1.4&0.8&0.9&2.0&0.8&0.8&0.8&0.8\cr\noalign{\vrule}
    Pit Width (cm)&4.2&3.7&3.0&2.3&3.1&2.5&2.1&3.9&3.6&7.0&4.1&2.0&2.5&3.0&3.0&4.0&4.1&3.8&3.2&3.8&2.5&5.0&3.6&3.1&3.1&2.9&0.9&0.8&3.0&0.8&0.8&0.8&0.8\cr\noalign{\vrule}
    Nearest Neighbor (cm)&6.00&12.04&6.00&10.63&3.16&2.24&2.24&3.16&3.16&3.16&3.16&10.20&6.40&7.00&8.00&9.06&3.61&3.61&7.07&3.00&3.00&5.00&6.00&5.10&7.00&5.10&2.24&2.24&5.83&2.24&6.40&2.24&4.47\cr\noalign{\vrule}
}
```

[image: Current (close to desired) valign]
I want to be able to remove the `\hsize1.5in` clause. I've attempted to use:

```
\def\make#1{{\vfil\hbox{\strut #1}\vfil\hrule}}
```

but this isn't sufficient because the text is not centered (and none of the paragraph typesetting tools like `\leftskip` or `\rightskip` can be used because paragraph setting uses `\hsize` to develop its boxes).

The other approach I've considered is using a `\halign`. This becomes much more hacky, and I haven't even found a consistent/automatic way of implementing a `\multirow` and `\cline` equivalent (drawing from LaTeX terminology), because as far as I can tell, they require a more complex tabular infrastructure. But if I can get this to work, `\hfil$\vcenter{#1}$\hfil` allows centering across both axes.

This style is clearly *possible* given LaTeX's ability to implement this (with `tabular+multirow`). Is the relevant infrastructure simple enough to partially reimplement, or should I just try to use a less general method (like boxing the column headers and presetting each column's `\hsize` based on that)? Or maybe I'm just missing some critical information that `\halign` (or a primitive relevant to `\valign`) is able to provide.

Comment: halign is usually easier to deal with than valign (latex basically never uses valign at all)

Comment: Just like `\halign` wraps every cell in an `\hbox`, `\valign` wraps in a `\vbox`; you *need* to set the `\hsize` if you want that `\centerline` does something neat, or it would use the value of `\hsize` valid outside. Why not `\hbox to1.5in{\hfil\strut#1\hfil}`?

Comment: @egreg I want the "default" behavior of tables where they flex to fit the contents of each cell instead of requiring a fixed size column. My objection isn't really specific to the `\hsize` primitive; `\hbox to 1.5in{\hfil\strut #1\hfil}` does look a bit cleaner, but it's got the same problems.

Comment: @HoldenRohrer So “centering” with respect to what? With `\valign` the *height* is adapted, not the width. Are you really sure you want a caged table?

Comment: @egreg If possible, horizontally, on a "line" the same width as the largest cell in the same column.

Comment: @HoldenRohrer You can't. Think to the same problem by transposing and using `\halign`.

Comment: " I want the "default" behavior of tables where they flex to fit the contents of each cell instead of requiring a fixed size column."  that's the behaviour of halign not valign

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you want the normal table behaviour that column widths are based on the width of the content, you want `\halign` not `\valign` so something like this (or more simply just use latex tabular, which is basically the same)

[image]

```
{\offinterlineskip
\setbox\strutbox=\hbox{\vrule height12pt depth3pt width0pt }
\def\cline{\omit\vrule\hfill\vrule&\multispan{3}{\kern-2pt\leaders\hrule\hfill}\cr}
%etex or use \addvance etc, 15.4 = height of large strut + one \hrule
\def\multirow#1#2{\smash{\lower0.5\dimexpr\numexpr#1-1\relax
\dimexpr15.4pt\relax\relax\hbox{\hss#2\hss}}}
\halign{%
\vrule\kern2pt\strut\hfill\ignorespaces#\unskip\hfill\kern4pt\vrule\kern2pt&%
\kern2pt\hfill\ignorespaces#\unskip\hfill\kern2pt\vrule\kern2pt&
\kern2pt\hfill\ignorespaces#\unskip\hfill\kern2pt\vrule\kern2pt&
\kern2pt\hfill\ignorespaces#\unskip\hfill\kern2pt\vrule\cr
\noalign{\hrule}
Dimensions (in)& Pit Depth (cm)& Pit Width (cm)&Nearest Neighbor (cm)\cr
\noalign{\hrule}
\multirow{9}{33$\times$32}
&1.2&4.5&2.8\cr
\cline
&1.2&4.5&2.8\cr
\cline
&1.2&4.5&2.8\cr
\cline
&1.2&4.5&2.8\cr
\cline
&1.2&4.5&2.8\cr
\cline
&1.2&4.5&2.8\cr
\cline
&1.2&4.5&2.8\cr
\cline
&1.2&4.5&2.8\cr
\cline
&1.2&4.5&2.8\cr
\noalign{\hrule}
\multirow{7}{24$\times$24}
&2.3&4.5&3.8\cr
\cline
&2.3&4.5&3.8\cr
\cline
&2.3&4.5&3.8\cr
\cline
&2.3&4.5&3.8\cr
\cline
&2.3&4.5&3.8\cr
\cline
&2.3&4.5&3.8\cr
\cline
&2.3&4.5&3.8\cr
\noalign{\hrule}
}

}
\bye
```

Comment: Absolutely ingenious. Thanks!

Comment: @HoldenRohrer it was ingenious when Leslie set it up in the 1980s, now choosing not to use 30 years of tex development and sticking to plain seems... strange?

Comment: Fair. I should probably switch

Comment: Why two consecutive \relax in the definition of \multirow?

Comment: @RaoulKessels closing the two open `\dimexpr`

Comment: Because the previous \relax closes the \numexpr. Now I see it. Thx